# Meteor css debug Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, meteor, less

For some reason that is beyond me, I can't debug less when `twbs:boostrap` is installed in my meteor app. When I remove it, chrome debugging works as it should. When I add it back, the CSS is concatenated as in production mode and I can't access it from the browser. I've tried running in debug mode `meteor debug`, and also tried reverting to other BS3 packages but it makes no difference. The `.less` files build properly, but I can't debug.

Any ideas for a fix?

Thanks,
db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `.map` files in the `twbs:bootstrap` package. My solution was to remove the official package, download the bootstrap files and add them manually to the `client` dir, excluding the `.map` files. Now I can debug properly.